# What causes the failure of a custom filter in this Vue 3 application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on a *Users* CRUD application with Vue 3. I want to display the users in reverse order (the latest addition should be on top) and for this purpose, I use the custom filter bolow:

```
reverse(array) {
  return array.slice().reverse();
}
```

Instead of the desired result, I get a `Property "reverse" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance` error.

```js
const usersApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [{
          id: 1,
          first_name: "John",
          last_name: "Doe",
          email: "john.doe@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          first_name: "Jane",
          last_name: "Doe",
          email: "jane.doe@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      formData: {
        first_name: "",
        last_name: "",
        email: ""
      },
      formErrors: [],
      userAdded: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    isNotEmpty() {
      return (
        this.formData.first_name &&
        this.formData.last_name &&
        this.formData.email
      );
    },
    isEmail(email) {
      return String(email)
        .toLowerCase()
        .match(
          /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        );
    },
    formValidation() {
      this.formErrors = [];

      if (!this.isNotEmpty()) {
        this.formErrors.push("There are empty filelds");
      }

      if (this.isNotEmpty() && !this.isEmail(this.formData.email)) {
        this.formErrors.push("The email is invalid");
      }
    },
    resetAddFormData() {
      this.formData.first_name = "";
      this.formData.last_name = "";
      this.formData.email = "";
      this.userAdded = false;
    },
    addUser() {
      // Validate form data
      this.formValidation();

      // Make New User
      let newUser = {
        first_name: this.formData.first_name,
        last_name: this.formData.last_name,
        email: this.formData.email
      };

      // Add new user
      if (!this.formErrors.length) {
        this.users.push(newUser);
        this.userAdded = true;
        window.setTimeout(this.resetAddFormData, 1000);
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    users() {
      this.users();
    }
  },
  filters: {
    reverse(array) {
      return array.slice().reverse();
    }
  }
};

Vue.createApp(usersApp).mount("#app");
```

```css
.logo {
  width: 30px;
}

.nav-item {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-item {
    width: auto;
  }
}

.user-row {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}

.user-row-active {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.alert {
  padding: 0.6rem 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>


<div id="app">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand p-0" href="#">
      <img src="https://www.pngrepo.com/png/303293/180/bootstrap-4-logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
    </a>

    <!-- Links -->
    <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
            Add user
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card my-2">
      <h5 class="card-header px-2">Users</h5>
      <div class="card-body p-0">
        <table class="table table-striped m-0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>
              <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody name="users-table" is="transition-group">
            <tr v-for="user in users | reverse" :key="user.id" class="user-row">
              <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
              <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
              <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title h6" id="exampleModalLongTitle">New User</h3>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @click="resetAddFormData">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div v-if="this.formErrors.length">
            <div v-for="error in formErrors" class="alert alert-danger">
              {{error}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div v-if="userAdded" class="alert alert-success">User added successfully!</div>
          <form @submit.prevent="addUser" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="First name" v-model="formData.first_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Last name" v-model="formData.last_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
              <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email address" v-model="formData.email">
            </div>
            <div class=" mt-2">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

#### Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there a better alternative to using a filter for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) say filters can be used for common text formatting, therefore you can't use it over the array element, so the alternative solution to get a reversed array is to use [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

So you can create a computed property like this:

```js
reversedUsers() {
  return this.users.slice().reverse();
}
```

Then get the results as below:

```js
const usersApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [{
          id: 1,
          first_name: "John",
          last_name: "Doe",
          email: "john.doe@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          first_name: "Jane",
          last_name: "Doe",
          email: "jane.doe@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      formData: {
        first_name: "",
        last_name: "",
        email: ""
      },
      formErrors: [],
      userAdded: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    isNotEmpty() {
      return (
        this.formData.first_name &&
        this.formData.last_name &&
        this.formData.email
      );
    },
    isEmail(email) {
      return String(email)
        .toLowerCase()
        .match(
          /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        );
    },
    formValidation() {
      this.formErrors = [];

      if (!this.isNotEmpty()) {
        this.formErrors.push("There are empty filelds");
      }

      if (this.isNotEmpty() && !this.isEmail(this.formData.email)) {
        this.formErrors.push("The email is invalid");
      }
    },
    resetAddFormData() {
      this.formData.first_name = "";
      this.formData.last_name = "";
      this.formData.email = "";
      this.userAdded = false;
    },
    addUser() {
      // Validate form data
      this.formValidation();

      // Make New User
      let newUser = {
        first_name: this.formData.first_name,
        last_name: this.formData.last_name,
        email: this.formData.email
      };

      // Add new user
      if (!this.formErrors.length) {
        this.users.push(newUser);
        this.userAdded = true;
        window.setTimeout(this.resetAddFormData, 1000);
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    users() {
      this.users();
    }
  },
  computed: {
    reversedUsers() {
      return this.users.slice().reverse();
    }
  }
};

Vue.createApp(usersApp).mount("#app");
```

```css
.logo {
  width: 30px;
}

.nav-item {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-item {
    width: auto;
  }
}

.user-row {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}

.user-row-active {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.alert {
  padding: 0.6rem 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>


<div id="app">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand p-0" href="#">
      <img src="https://www.pngrepo.com/png/303293/180/bootstrap-4-logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
    </a>

    <!-- Links -->
    <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
            Add user
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card my-2">
      <h5 class="card-header px-2">Users</h5>
      <div class="card-body p-0">
        <table class="table table-striped m-0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Firstname</th>
              <th>Lastname</th>
              <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody name="users-table" is="transition-group">
            <tr v-for="user in reversedUsers" :key="user.id" class="user-row">
              <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
              <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
              <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title h6" id="exampleModalLongTitle">New User</h3>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @click="resetAddFormData">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div v-if="this.formErrors.length">
            <div v-for="error in formErrors" class="alert alert-danger">
              {{error}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div v-if="userAdded" class="alert alert-success">User added successfully!</div>
          <form @submit.prevent="addUser" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="First name" v-model="formData.first_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Last name" v-model="formData.last_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
              <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email address" v-model="formData.email">
            </div>
            <div class=" mt-2">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```